# How join to a random row, in another table, in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

One list things - `thing_id, thing_name, thing_status`

Other table lists attributes of each thing.

```
attribute_id, attribute_thing, attribute_name, attribute_status
```

`thing_id` = `attribute_thing`

I basically I want to grab a random thing that has a `thing_status = 1` and then I need to JOIN it to a random attribute which would have `attribute_status = 1`

Each thing may have 0 to N attributes, and 0 attribute things should still be returned. If a thing has more than 1 attribute, a random one should be returned.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM things
LEFT JOIN attributes ON thing_id = attribute_thing AND attribute_status = 1
WHERE thing_status = 1
GROUP BY thing_id
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 1
```

The problem here, is that it always JOINs to the first attribute (with the lowest `attribute_id` for that thing. I need to pick a random one.

Removing the GROUP BY clause kind of works, however things with many attributes are much more likely to be picked. So a thing with 30 attributes would be 30 times as likely to be picked than a thing that has 1 attribute. I want all things to be treated equally.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only 1 integer column from attributes, you could do something like:

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(attributes.id ORDER BY RAND() SEPARATOR ',')),',',1)
```

... if you need more, I see no alternatives other nesting some subqueries.

Comment: No, I need the whole thing (there are more columns that I omitted)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    things a
LEFT JOIN
    attributes b ON a.thing_id = b.attribute_things AND b.attribute_status = 1
WHERE
    a.thing_id = 
    (
        SELECT c.thing_id
        FROM
        (
            SELECT thing_id
            FROM things
            WHERE thing_status = 1
            ORDER BY RAND()
            LIMIT 1
        ) c
    )
ORDER BY
    RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

To get a random value from a subquery via `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`, turns out you have the wrap the subquery in *another* subquery.

Comment: Im getting an error: Unknown column 'a.thing_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: See edit. You should get a random thing, as well as a random attribute associated with that thing, satisfying the status conditions.

Comment: I mentioned the GROUP BY at the bottom of my original post.

Comment: Okay we're going to have to use a subquery on the `things` table for that. Problem is that getting a random value in a subquery doesn't seem to work in MySQL. I will work more on this later when I get back home unless someone provides a better solution.

Comment: See edit. I got the random selection of thing from subquery working. The random thing selection is independent from how many attribute rows it contains in the attributes table.

Comment: I've actually used your pre-edited version with a slight modification and it works. The LEFT JOIN has to be a subquery, which is less messy than a nested subquery that you have now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12462/discussion-between-k1lljoy-and-zane-bien)

Comment: Great! I'm curious as to how you wrote it w/ the LEFT JOIN. Would you care to share your final solution?